# Contract methods calls return empty array

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-deployment

I'm quite stuck with this issue. It seems like it must work, but it doesn't :D

Have a contract on `rinkeby` network which is working perfectly through remix(load by address) and truffle console. However method calls through `web3` client refuse to work.

**init:**

```
import Web3 from 'web3';


// @ts-ignore
const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);

***got address & abi***

export default new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
```

**usage example:**

```
console.log(registryContract.options.address);
console.log(registryContract.methods);
const owner = await registryContract.methods.owner().call();
```

In `console.log()` i can see the actual contract address and methods.
Metamask is active and `web3.eth.defaultAccount` shows me my correct account at `rinkeby` network => provider must be working.

calling the `owner` from remix working. with web3 i'm getting an empty array as response. Same for other methods calls.

What is possible going wrong? `"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.37"`

Comment: is there any solution you got ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was with contract `abi` - don't know what exactly was wrong with it. I simply used `abi` from different source and it helped. Any tool for `abi` verification?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "direct source"?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue and managed to solve it by passing correct ABI object. Looks like earlier versions of solc returned ABI as a JSON string and current version returns actual JavaScript object (but I'm not sure). So you can't just print contract's ABI and paste it to web3 instance (as I did). I had to JSON.stringify returned object first and then JSON.parse copy/pasted string to the web3 instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have some stray brackets after the method name.

Instead of

```
registryContract.methods.owner().call();
```

try

```
registryContract.methods.owner.call();
```

Comment: tried using it without `()` returns me `methods.owner` object

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
registryContract.owner(function (error, result) {
if (!error)
  console.log(result);
else
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: tried, doesn't throw any error

Answer (score 0):

Encountered exactly the same problem (all methods returning empty arrays) and was driving me mad.

The solution (the one I found anyway) was to stringify the abi resulting from the solc compiler (as mentioned earlier in this thread).

> console.log(JSON.stringify(abi)); // AND NOT console.log(abi)

And to copy&paste the resulting string copy&pasted to specify the deployed contract's abi.

*And pending question, any way to check that a the proxy obtained on a deployed contract using its address and associated abi is correct ?*

That would have saved me a lot of time and would probably save time for many more to come.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies with the ABI you are feeding to web3.eth.Contract and you need a comprehensive one. Go to https://remix.ethereum.org/ and compile your contract there, then copy the ABI from there.

[image: You can find the copy button at the bottom of this image.]

You can find the copy button for the ABI at the bottom of this image.